# How to make edit control not accept 0 as first digit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Well, I have an edit that takes only numbers (no letters, no symbols, only numbers). The problem is that i don't want the user to put 0 as the first digit, for example (0239847).

I was thinking of making a variable "x" --> byte   which will count the lenght of the edit and delete the first digit, if it is 0:

```
var l:length; number:string100;
begin
l:length(edit1.text);
```

Now if the first digit is 0 (0239847), then delete it, BUT if there are not other numbers (only 0), leave it as it is.

Omg, i finally found the easiest way to do this:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var digit1:string;
begin
digit1:=edit1.Text;
if (digit1='00') or (digit1='01') or (digit1='02') or (digit1='03') or (digit1='04') or
(digit1='05') or (digit1='06') or (digit1='07') or (digit1='08') or (digit1='09') then
edit1.Text:=clear;    //or edit1.text:=0;  it's the same

end;

end.
```

The can still copy and paste numbers, but i don't mind

It was a pretty silly question, because the answer was easy and obvious, but if you are way too tired, it is hard to find it, i am sorry for getting you busy for this, Andreas, thanks for your help and tips.

Comment: I'm sorry, the question isn't clear. First, surely you mean 'as the first **digit**', not 'number'. Second, it the question about a custom   control derived from `TCustomEdit`?

Comment: Yes, the first digit, and i don't know what's TcustomEdit, not, it's just TEdit

Comment: But then how have you made it accept only digits? Have you used `OnChange`, `OnKeyPress`, ...? [Anyhow: If the control is a `TEdit`, then it *is* in fact derived from `TCustomEdit`! :) ]

Comment: The trouble you are experiencing is the computers way of telling you not to do this. Do not do this! Validate later. Imagine what happens when the user has typed in `2000087287632453451` and wants to change the first digit from a `2` to a `1`. They go into the edit control. Then press `HOME`. Then press `DELETE`, and then press `1`. Now the edit reads `1000087287632453451`. Your user now hates you with a passion, and with just cause.

Comment: @David: I'd press `Home`, `Shift+Right`, `1`, `End`, and everything would work. [But that was an irrelevant comment: you are very right, of course.]

Comment: It's a mistake made over and over again. The idea that the contents of an edit control must be valid every single instant in time. That path leads to UI that makes your life a misery.

Comment: This may be true, but I don't think that deserves a downvote, whoever did that?

Comment: Question doesn't deserve a downvote, it's perfectly clear and well asked

Comment: @David: As the downvoter, I disagree. In order to provide a good answer, I'd like to know exactly *how* the current functionality ('numbers only') is provided. Also, I'd like to know some more of the context: for instance, why do you need this particular prettification? Do you need other verifications/prettifications as well? Do you need real-time prettification? In addition, the original post used the term 'number' instead of 'digit' and contained a nonsense code snippet.

Comment: Still, I removed the downvote. My comment above is much more constructive.

Comment: The reason your code doesn't do anything is that it doesn't do anything! `Exit` simply exits the procedure, so if this is the last statement in your procedure, it is trivially a no-op.

Comment: Yeah, you are right ,if it was a button it would work, but now it's just an edit, so what should i do, insteed of following the code you have written above, which is confusing

Comment: @user2296565: I could easily give you a two-line answer that does prevent most cases of leading zeroes, but such a simple solution would almost certainly have 'quirks', such as the possibility to circumvent the 'no leading zeroes' rule, or 'caret hopping', or something similar.

Comment: You don't want a '0' to be entered as first character but in your solution you allow '0' to be entered as the first character. You also make it as if '0' is entered if someone writes '01'. I don't understand it. Maybe you'd like to modify the question so that your solution solves a problem in the question.

Comment: If 01 is written, then edit1.text will be 0. But yes, you are right, i should have made it: then edit1.text:=clear;

Comment: I don't quite get your solution, but the conditional can be simplified a lot: `if (length(S) >= 2) and (S[1] = '0') and (S[2] in ['0'..'9']) then`

Comment: Anyhow, I don't think your solution is acceptable. For instance, if the edit field is empty, and you enter `020`, then the result will be `0`, and not `20` as I would expect. Also, if the edit field contains more than two character (3 or more), then you can add any number of leading zeroes just by ... adding them! I'm sorry, but your solution is a usability nightmare!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is hard to do this well. The most ambitious approach would be to do a lot of logic on key down, paste, etc., like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069650/282848). You'd be surprised how many cases there are to handle!

This works pretty well, I think:

```
type
  TEdit = class(StdCtrls.TEdit)

...

procedure TEdit.KeyPress(var Key: Char);

  function InvalidKey: boolean;
  begin
     InvalidKey :=
       (
         (Key = '0') and
           (
             ((SelStart = 0) and (Length(Text) - SelLength <> 0))
             or
             ((SelStart = 1) and (Text[1] = '0'))
           )
       )
       or
       (
         not (Key in ['0'..'9', #8, ^Z, ^X, ^C, ^V])
       )
  end;

begin
  inherited;

  if InvalidKey then
  begin
    beep;
    Key := #0;
  end else if (SelStart = 1) and (Text[1] = '0') then
  begin
    Text := Copy(Text, 2);
  end;
end;

procedure TEdit.WMPaste(var Message: TWMPaste);    
var
  ClipbrdText: string;

  function ValidText: boolean;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    result := true;
    for i := 1 to Length(ClipbrdText) do
      if not (ClipbrdText[i] in ['0'..'9']) then
      begin
        result := false;
        break;
      end;
  end;

  function RemoveLeadingZeros(const S: string): string;
  var
    NumLeadingZeros: integer;
    i: Integer;
  begin
    NumLeadingZeros := 0;
    for i := 1 to Length(S) do
      if S[i] = '0' then
        inc(NumLeadingZeros)
      else
        break;
    result := Copy(S, NumLeadingZeros + 1);
  end;

begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
  begin

    ClipbrdText := Clipboard.AsText;

    if not ValidText then
    begin
      beep;
      Exit;
    end;

    if SelStart = 0 then
      ClipbrdText := RemoveLeadingZeros(ClipbrdText);

    SelText := ClipbrdText;

  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

This looks complicated, but all this logic is necessary. For instance, the code handles all these cases well:

- You can only enter digits.
- If `SelStart = 0` and *not every* character is selected, you cannot enter `0`, because then you would get a leading zero.
- If `SelStart = 0` and *every* character is selected, you *can* enter `0`. Because you should be able to enter this valid number.

  - A special case: If there are zero characters, then of course zero characters are selected, so by simply logic you *will* be able to enter `0` from the state of the empty string!
- If `SelStart = 1` and the `Text[1] = '0'` [if `SelStart = 1`, then `Text[1]` exists, so we rely on boolean short-circuit evaluation here], then you cannot enter `0`.
- If the contents of the edit field is `0` and you add a non-zero character after the zero, then the zero is removed (and there is no interference with the caret position).
- You can only paste digits. If `SelStart = 0`, leading zeros (in the clipboard data) are discarded.

In fact, to make the behaviour perfect, you need *even more* code. For instance, suppose that the contents of the edit field is `123000456`. As it is now, you can select the first three characters (`123`) and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> to obtain the invalid text `000456`. The solution is to *add extra code* that removes leading zeroes resulting from either of these two operations. **Update:** I have been doing some thinking, and have come to realise that it is probably best *not* to implement this (why?).

One shortcut, however, would be to 'prettify' the contents of the edit when it isn't focused, because when it isn't, you are much less likely to shoot the user in the foot by doing something with the contents of the edit.

For instance, you can do something like

```
function PrettifyNumber(const S: string): string;
var
  NumLeadingZeros: integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  NumLeadingZeros := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[i] = '0' then
      inc(NumLeadingZeros)
    else
      break;
  result := Copy(S, NumLeadingZeros + 1);
  if length(result) = 0 then
    result := S;
end;
```

and then replace the contents of the edit field by its prettified version when it loses keyboard focus. Of course, you should consider adding this functionality to a derived edit class, but for testing you can simply use the `OnExit` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := PrettifyNumber(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

I suppose that you want this functionality in a lot of edits in a major application (or not so major). So you will in fact write your own subclassed control. Then I suppose you will also need other types of verification than simply removal of leading zeros? You thus have to integrate this code nicely with the rest of the code. If in fact you will use this edit 'subclass' everywhere in a big application, you could also consider adding a shortcut, to the edit control class, so that you can prettify/verify the text on demand, and not only on exit (which is particularly difficult if the edit control is alone on its form!)

## Update

On request, this is a simple solution that works badly:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = '0') and (Edit1.SelStart = 0) then Key := #0;
end;
```

I leave it as an exercise to figure out the issues with this approach. If you fix the issues, one by one, as you discover them, you will end up with my long code above!

Comment: Well, this is working, but if i more than 9 numbers it says that the number i have put in edit is not a valid integer value...What should i do?

Comment: @user2296565: Please don't use the word 'numbers' if you mean 'digits'. As I wrote, the number cannot exceed 2147483647, which is 2^31 - 1.

Comment: Imagine what happens when you type and the caret is in the middle of the number

Comment: @David: I actually tried that, and it didn't cause any discomfort (which surprised me). [If it would have, however, the workaround wouldn't have been hard to implement.]

Comment: uuh, Andreas, you have done a mistake, parametres are missing:the correct is S:=copy(s,numleadingzeros,+1), But that does not delete the 0 if it is first

Comment: @user2296565: No, there are no parameters missing. There should be exactly two parameters to `copy`. No comma! For instance, if `NumLeadingZeros` is `5`, then `Copy(S, NumLeadingZeros + 1)` is `S` from character `6` to its end. On the contrary, `Copy(S, NumLeadingZeros, 1)` would given you a string of length `1`, namely, the last leading zero only!!

Comment: but it says that parametres are missing and does not run the program

Comment: @user2296565: I am using Delphi 2009. Perhaps the you need all three in Delphi 7. If so, the last parameter can be any number greater or equal to the number of characters you want to copy. Simply use `Length(S)` as the third parameter.

Comment: l:byte;
s:string100;
begin
L:=length(s);
if (L=1) and(s[1]='0') then exit;
s:=s+'0';
edit1.text:=s;        I have used this code in the past to create a calculator and i didn't allow the user to press the button 0 in the beggining, how do i do the same with the edit?

Comment: @user2296565: No, there isn't. If you simplify the code, you will get something that works most of the time, but behaves badly under special circumstances. For instance, my code works even if you have `12345`, select the first four characters, and press `0`. The code won't let you! But if you have selected all five characters, then the code lets you enter `0`. Indeed, how would you otherwise enter the valid number `0`? Also, if you got `0`, the caret is to the right of `0`, and you press `0` you should get a beep. But if you press any other digit, the zero needs to be rmd & the dig. inserted!

Comment: In fact, to make this work really well, you need *even more* code. As it is now, the user can simply paste any number of leading zeroes into the edit field.

Comment: I added handling of WM_PASTE. Now you can only paste numeric text, and leading zeroes are handled correctly. For instance, if the clipboard contains `0012` and you paste *at the beginning of the text*, then leading zeroes are automatically removed. But if you paste `0012` after some non-zero digits, then the zeroes are kept.

Comment: @user2296565 How on earth have you not upvoted this answer? Look at all the effort Andreas is putting in for you here. It's funny how the number of votes an answer gets is often inversely proportional to the effort involved.

Comment: i was about to upvote it and mark it as my answer, but still we are trying to solve this problem

Comment: @user2296565: Which problem?

Comment: @user2296565: you've received way more than you deserve, based on your unthankful attitude. This is an awesome help. I'll probably visit this answer in the future when i need some input validation. Thanks for the efforts Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

You could use TmaskEdit. This force the user to input the numbers. After add eventchange for delete first digit if 0.

Example.dfm

```
.
.
object MaskEdit1: TMaskEdit
  Left = 352
   Top = 8
   Width = 120
   Height = 21
   EditMask = '0999999;0;_'
   MaxLength = 7
   TabOrder = 3
   OnChange = MaskEdit1Change
end
.
.
```

Example.pas

```
.
.
Procedure TForm1.MaskEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  If Length(TMaskEdit(Sender).Text) > 1 Then
    TMaskEdit(Sender).Text := IntToStr(StrToInt(TMaskEdit(Sender).Text));
End;
.
.
```